# Indexing Taggit tags with Algolia for Django: '_TaggableManager' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: django, algolia, django-taggit

I'm having some issues using the [Algolia Django integration](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-django) with one of my models which contains a `TaggitManager()` field. I'm currently being thrown back the following error when running this command:

```
$ python manage.py algolia_reindex

AttributeError: '_TaggableManager' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I've had a look at the [Taggit documentation](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html), but I'm just not sure exactly how I would marry the method outlined with the Algolia search index method.

index.py:

```
import django
django.setup()

from algoliasearch_django import AlgoliaIndex

class BlogPostIndex(AlgoliaIndex):
    fields = ('title')
    settings = {'searchableAttributes': ['title']}
    index_name = 'blog_post_index'
```

models.py:

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Post(models.Model):
    ...some model fields...

    tags = TaggableManager()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To index the `taggit` tags with your Post fields, you will need to **expose a callable** that returns a Blog Post's tags as a **list of strings**.

The best option is to store them as `_tags`, which will let you [filter on tags at query time](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/python/parameters/tagFilters/).

Your `PostIndex` would look like this:

```
class PostIndex(AlgoliaIndex):
    fields = ('title', '_tags')
    settings = {'searchableAttributes': ['title']}
    index_name = 'Blog Posts Index'
    should_index = 'is_published'
```

As for `Post`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # ...some model fields...

    tags = TaggableManager()

    def _tags(self):
        return [t.name for t in self.tags.all()]
```

Following these instructions, your records will be indexed with their respective tags:

[image: Screenshot of a tagAlgolia explorer]

You can check the [`taggit` branch](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-django-example/tree/taggit) of our Django demo, which demonstrates these steps.

Comment: Would it be possible to go to live chat?

Comment: Hi Michael, live-chat is provided to Algolia's entreprise customers only. If you are one, simply log-in to your dashboard and click the `Need Help?` button. If you are not yet an entreprise customer, you can send your support request to support@algolia.com :)

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question. I have now passed in both the model and the model index so Algolia now knows what to index and what not to index. Although I would like a method to allow Algolia to index taggit tags, alas, it is probably not possible.

My apps.py file:

```
import algoliasearch_django as algoliasearch
from django.apps import AppConfig
from .index import PostIndex

class BlogConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'blog'

    def ready(self):
        Post = self.get_model('Post')
        algoliasearch.register(Post, PostIndex)
```

My index.py file:

```
from algoliasearch_django import AlgoliaIndex

class PostIndex(AlgoliaIndex):
    fields = ('title')
    settings = {'searchableAttributes': ['title']}
    index_name = 'Blog Posts Index'
    should_index = 'is_published'
```

And that should pretty much work! Simple when you know how, or after trying about 10 different options!

Comment: Hi Michael, Algolia's Django integration maintainer here. Indeed with the current version your solution is the best way to go. This being said I'm currently investigating `taggit` to see how we could index these tags, I'll keep you updated here!

Comment: @PLNech Awesome. I think the issue lies more with taggit than with Algolia. Still, I think between us we have implemented temporary workarounds.

Comment: Indeed the issue probably stems from `_TaggableManager` not exposing a `name` field like other Django Managers, as shown by @hansTheFranz in his workaround. Regardless, check my answer for a clean way to index your tags properly :)

Answer (score 0):

So since nobody is answering I tell you how I solved this issue but I have to say that it is not a nice Way and not a "clean" Solution at all. So what I did is went into "taggit managers" in the site-packages (env->lib->python2.x/3.x-> site_packages->taggit->managers.py) In the managers.py file you will find at line 394 this beautiful piece of code:

```
def __get__(self, instance, model):
            if instance is not None and instance.pk is None:
                raise ValueError("%s objects need to have a primary key value "
                                 "before you can access their tags." % model.__name__)
            manager = self.manager(
                through=self.through,
                model=model,
                instance=instance,
                prefetch_cache_name=self.name,  # this is the line I comment out when building the index,
                name=self.name  #this is the line I added and needs to be commented out after the index is build. 
            )
            return manager
```

So what I do when I want to rebuild the search index is comment out (putting"#" infront of the line) `prefetch_cache_name=self.name,` and replace it with `name=self.name`. So building the index will work. After the Index is finished building, you have to bring everything back as it was before (switch the "#" to `name=self.name` again and leave `prefetch_cache_name=self.name,` visible again).

As already mentioned this is probably not the best way but I had the same pain and this is working for me. It takes one minute when you have the routine.  Since I have to rebuild the Index maybe once every two weeks, that isn't such a deal for me but if you have to do it very often this might be annoying...

Anyway I hope that helps you.

Comment: Hi @hanzTheFranz I admire the guts of putting something like this up - but I wouldn't guarantee that this won't break something further down the line.

Answer (score 0):

It can help you if you using `django==2+`

The problem is in `get_queryset()` method of `TaggableManager`

Open file with it (my path was: `Pipenv(project_name)/lib/site-packages/taggit/manager.py`)
Find `_TaggableManager` class and change method name `get_queryset` to `get_query_set`

Done. I wish taggit's developers will fixed this in future updates